# Web notifications,On Desktop Receiving all the notification at the same time

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-notifications

I have sent two notifications one in the morning and one in the afternoon.
My laptop is open for the whole time. However, I receive both the notifications at the same time i.e. in the afternoon.

For some users this behavior is even worse they are receiving 6-7 notifications at the same time.
Can anyone explain why there is such a behavior/ provide a solution for it?

Comment: How are you sending it? With nodejs push library ?

Comment: No, we are making a Rest API calls using .net framework.